# Python calling math.log on big number returns number with 1 in last decimal place instead of whole number

Tags: python

So I was doing the following programming problem:

```
Find if the given number is power of 2 or not.
```

Since log is inverse of exponent, I came up with a solution where I would get the log2 of the number, and if that result was a whole number (by testing with % 1) then it is a power of 2.

```
def isPowerOfTwo(n):
if n == 1:
    return 0
if math.log(n, 2) % 1 == 0:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

However this fails on the number 5070602400912917605986812821504, since math.log(5070602400912917605986812821504, 2) returns 102.00000000000001 for some reason.

What is going on here for there to be that 1 in the last decimal place? According to every calculator I tried, log base 2 of 5070602400912917605986812821504 is just 102.

Comment: that is because the result of math.log is always a float

Comment: Using `math.log2` should alleviate matters.  By the way, 1 is a power of 2 also (2^0).

Comment: Another, sillier way: `sum(int(x) for x in bin(n)[2:]) == 1` and never worry about floatpoint arithmetic :)

Comment: Which calculators did you try, specifically?  And what do they return if you give them 5070602400912917605986812821505 instead (that is, 1 larger than the integer you're actually using)?  In general, you cannot using floating-point facilities to get exact answers about integers larger than 2**53-1 (floats in Python have 53 bits of precision).

Comment: By the way, the fastest way to test whether `n` is a power of 2 is to check whether `n & (n-1)` equals `0`.  In general, `n & (n-1)` is the value of `n` with its least-significant `1` bit cleared.  `n` is a power of 2 if and only if its least-significant `1` bit is its _only_ `1` bit, in which case clearing it leaves just `0`.  Although `0` is a special case for this method (`0 & -1 == 0` too, but `0` isn't generally considered to be a power of 2).